# Executing a Kusto function residing on leader cluster from follower cluster

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Lets say I have a user defined function `MyFunction()` which is created in a leader cluster in database `MyDatabase` which is being followed by a follower cluster. Now if I execute the function from the follower cluster , where cluster is it being actually executed on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be executed on the follower cluster. The function is always in the context of the database, and thus will execute in that database, if it is a follower database it will be executed in the follower cluster.